# How to get pandas' read_html() to ignore hidden tables?

Tags: python, html, pandas

I want read the tables from the following url [interactive brokers site with margin requirements](https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/en/index.php?f=40539&hm=us&ex=us&rgt=0&rsk=1&pm=0&rst=101004010808010801) into several pandas DataFrames.

In principle it works, but there are too much tables delivered back - the website only shows 13 tables but `read_html()` delivers 41:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/en/index.php?f=40539&hm=us&ex=us&rgt=0&rsk=1&pm=0&rst=101004010808010801'
all_tables = pd.read_html(url)
print("len(all_tables)=", len(all_tables))
print("all_tables[0]=\n", all_tables[0])
```

result:

```
len(all_tables)= 41
all_tables[0]=
   Exchange BELFOX  ... Short Overnight Maintenance
0          BELFOX  ...                       11250
[1 rows x 12 columns]
```

This table for the BELFOX exchange is not shown on the website, which is most probably the result of the

```
<div id="belfox" class="hide_table">
```

class as depicted in the excerpt from the html page:

---

[image: excerpt from html]

---

How would it be possible to tell pd.read_html() to ignore a table once this class appears for a table?

For the tables that have to appear, the class `show_table` is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- As per [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html), the `pd.read_html()` API wil only look for the `<table>` elements on a page, and does not care about the  `<div>` surrounding it. So in your case, the Pandas API will not be able to make the table selection for you. You will need a library like BeautifulSoup to remove the `<div>` elements with class `hide_table`
- The specific page you are referring to dynamically sets the classes visibility, so you cannot just make a simple request to fetch the html content of the page. You will need wait until the page has fully loaded, so you would need an additional library like Selenium

The following code does the trick for you:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd

# Fetch the dynamically loaded page
url = 'https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/en/index.php?f=40539&hm=us&ex=us&rgt=0&rsk=1&pm=0&rst=101004010808010801'
chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") # Opens the browser up in background
with Chrome(options=chrome_options) as browser:
     browser.get(url)
     html = browser.page_source

# Remove the divs with class="hide_table"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
removals = soup.find_all('div',class_='hide_table')
for match in removals:
    match.decompose()
    
# Load into Pandas
all_tables = pd.read_html(str(soup))
```